# Google App Engine Datastore Admin Console - Offline mode

Tags: google-app-engine, console, admin, google-cloud-datastore

Is there a good GAE Datastore Admin Console available in offline mode? I am currently working on designing a REST api using GAE, Flask and Google NDB. In GAE, there is a very nice administration console to let you view/edit the data models. Is there something similar when you're working on the localhost mode? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** This answer is out of date, see Asmo's answer.

---

There's an admin page at `http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin`, although it doesn't have all the features of the production admin console.

Answer (score 2):

In the latest GAE versions the datastore admin is part of the *development console* at `http://localhost:8000/`

More info:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Python_The_Development_Console